# Filter text and replace with html element by jquery

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a dummy text variable i.e

```
var text = 'This is a dummy text for filterable-text1 and I want to change filterable-text2'
```

I want to filter the word "filterable" and get an output like this:

```
var output = 'This is a dummy text for <span class="filterable-text1"></span> and I want to change <span class="filterable-text2"></span>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think regex is a good solution for that;

```
var output=text.replace(/(filterable-text[0-9]|football|cricket)/,'<span class="$1"></span>');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. one more question please. what if the text1 and text2 becomes different word like "footbal" and "cricket" or any other random text?

Comment: However if it is not possible then can I use text[0-100] if I have 100 items?

Comment: 0 to 999  would be [0-9]{1,3}  not [0-100] which eould be 0 to 1

Comment: Another if you won't mind how I can reverse the process i.e how var output = 'This is a dummy text for <span class="filterable-text1"></span> and I want to change <span class="filterable-text2"></span>' can be transferred to var text = 'This is a dummy text for filterable-text1 and I want to change filterable-text2'